# How to model a GET endpoint to accept date ranges for multiple values?

Tags: rest

We have a collection endpoint that has a fair deal of filtering. Many of the attributes being filtered are dates, and we want them to be able to filter for a range, or a min/max.

The way we've done it so far is to accept `some_date_filter[min]` and `some_date_filter[max]` (i.e., to act like a hash on the server side, so we get `{some_date_filter: {min: "2014-09-30T11:44:21-07:00", max: "2014-09-30T11:44:21-07:00"}}`). However, this seems like it could be done better. (Our API documenter even broke when we tried to document this, which raised some flags).

What would be a better way to design this API?

Answer (score 1):

I have never noticed anyone using [ and ] as part of url's and I would expect at least some tools to have trouble with it. Just use suffixes instead, so a url ends up looking like this

```
http://yourHost/getSomething?start-date-min=2014-09-30T11:44:21-07:00&start-date-max=2014-09-30T11:44:21-07:00&some-other-date-min=2014-09-30T11:44:21-07:00
```